# Is there a difference between returning byte array or servlet output stream on file download

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download

I'm wondering if there a real difference when a Sprin MVC controller method returns byte array `byte[]` to represent a downloaded file or when I copy `InputStream` object to the `ServletOutputStream` object?

The reason I'm asking is that I have to make sure that there won't be any OutOfMemory errors when downloading large files. Will the passing file through the `ServletOutputStream` help to avoid it?

Passing byte array:

```
byte[] download() {
    return getUrlContentAsByteArray();
}
```

Passing in the ServletOutputStream:

```
void download(HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream content = getUrlContentAsStream();
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.reset();response.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.getMimeType());
    IOUtils.copyLarge(inputStream, outputStream);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC here, or the Servlet API directly? If the latter (direct use of the Servlet API), what or who is invocing your `byte[] download()` method from the first example?

Comment: @GhostCat, it's controller methods, the second method uses response to return a value

Comment: @jarnbjo, its Spring MVC controllers. Sorry to miss it in the question.

Comment: The first one loads the whole file content in memory. The second one doesn't. If memory is a concern and/or the files are large, you shouldn't use the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, you have to read the entire response into memory and store it in a byte array. That will require *at least* as much memory as the size of the response.

In your second example, you do not keep the entire response in memory at once, but use `IOUtils.copy` to copy the content in multiple, small chunks from the source and into the servlet response. IOUtils is by default using a 4kB large buffer. You are however using a strange mix of both Spring and Servlet APIs.

Using Spring MVC alone, you can leave out the servlet API, return the InputStream wrapped as a Resource and let Spring do the copy job for you:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    InputStream is = null; // get your input stream here
    Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(is);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```